# ImportError during Unittest discover on tests root directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, testing, python-unittest

Running tests discover using these format works:

```
python -m unittest discover tests/folder1/folder2 -v
python -m unittest discover tests/folder1
```

The issue happens when I'm running the discover tests on the root directory of the tests scripts.

```
python -m unittest discover tests  # raised ImportError
```

My project structure looks like this:

```
project_name/
    src/
        __init__.py
        # modules
    tests/
        folder1/
            __init__.py
            folder2/
                # test scripts
                __init__.py
        __init__.py
```

Based on what I read on some related post, the issue was with the PATH. but I already include the src path by running this command and the ImportError still occurs.

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$(pwd)/src
```

python version: 3.5.0

Answer (score 1):

prepending `test_` to test folders fixed the issue.